# Find the integral of a harmonic function over a unit ball

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $B$  be the unit ball in ${{\text{R}}^{\text{3}}}$, and $u\in {{C}^{2}}\left( B \right)\cap C\left( {\bar{B}} \right)$ such that

$$\begin{array}{l}\Delta u = 0\quad in\quad B\\u\left( {x,y,z} \right) = {z^2} \quad if{\rm{ }}\left( {x,y,z} \right) \in \partial B,{\rm{ }}z \ge 0{\rm{ }}\\u\left( {x,y,z} \right) = {z}\quad if{\rm{ }}\left( {x,y,z} \right) \in \partial B,{\rm{ }}z < 0{\rm{ }}\end{array}
$$

Find the value of $\int_\Omega  {u\left( x \right)dx} $, where $\Omega =\left\{ \left( x,y,z \right)\in {{R}^{3}}:{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}+{{z}^{2}}<\frac{1}{4} \right\}$.

Do we do this by the mean-value formulas, and how?  Please help.  I have't seen similar problems before.

Comment: Use mean-value theorem for harmonic function, the integral is u(0) then use surface integral version to evaluate u(0) with unit ball centered at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [runaround](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/310548/runaround).

\begin{align}
  & u\left( 0 \right)=\frac{1}{\alpha }\int_{B\left( 0,R \right)}{u\left( x,y,z \right)dV}=\frac{1}{\omega }\int_{\partial B\left( 0,R \right)}{u\left( x,y,z \right)dA} \\ 
 & =\frac{1}{\omega }\int_{\partial B\left( 0,R \right)}{u\left( x,y,z \right)2\pi R\sin \phi Rd\phi } \\ 
 & =\frac{2\pi }{\omega }\left[ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{{{\left( R\cos \phi  \right)}^{2}}\cdot {{R}^{2}}\sin \phi d\phi +\int_{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\pi }{R\cos \phi \cdot {{R}^{2}}\sin \phi d\phi }} \right]  
\end{align}
where $\alpha $ is the volume of $B\left( 0,R \right)$, $\omega$ is it's surface, and $R=\frac{1}{2}$ .